# Pycharm Python console: What is "Variables Loading Policy"?

Tags: python, variables, pycharm

What is the Variables Loading Policy in Pycharm Python Console AND WHY would I want to use it?
I've looked up the doc'n here: [Pycharm Variable Loading Policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2020.3/variables-loading-policy.html)

and I'm still just as confused as ever.
What is the context that "Variable Loading Policy" is in?
Policy for what? Which variables??
It's not clear what it means to "load a variable". Yes, I know the diff b/tw synch/asynch. But variables in the script that the console runs get "loaded" regardless of "policy". Why do I care how they get loaded?

[image]

Comment: I'd think the variables it means are ones that you can hover over or see in the locals or watch lists. And as far as synchronous, async or on-demand, that makes perfect sense - synchronous would load them in order, async does it all at once, and on demand would just load them when you try to view the value. Does that make sense?

Comment: @RandomDavis: Nope. It's not even clear what it means to load a variable, and the "in order" vs "all at once" thing doesn't sound like what the page describes.

Comment: By loading, I mean reading the value from that variable to display in the debugger. Also, are you aware of the definitions of asynchronous versus synchronous? I was going off of the definitions of those words. But from looking at the page it's obvious to me that's what they mean.

Comment: @RandomDavis: From *my* read of the page, it looks more like asynchronous mode displays each value when it's ready and synchronous mode waits until all values are ready to display them. As for reading values, just reading a variable value is practically free. I would *guess* that what they really mean is some combination of `repr` computation and type-specific analysis (one of the screenshots shows a "...View as DataFrame" prompt for a dataframe), but it's really not clear.

Comment: RandomDavis, thanks for your response but: I agree w/ user 2357112. It's not clear what it means to "load a variable". Yes, I know the diff b/tw synch/asynch.
But variables in the script that the console runs get "loaded" regardless of "policy". Why do I care how they get loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console has a variable view where variable/value pairs are displayed. Imagine a class implementing `__str__` and the method either takes quite a lot of time or even trigger an exception. If PyCharm tries to load the instance string representation in this case you will either got stuck while it is calculated or will receive an error. That's why this option was introduced.

E.g. switching to "On demand" variable loading policy with prevent PyCharm to auto-load variable values

[image]

Comment: I've some @property values on a class that make API calls to get their data. For some reason even with on demand set, pycharm is still running these property functions immediately

Answer (score 2):

From Pycharm Support:

When you debug your code in PyCharm, you can preview the variable values.

["Examine/update variables"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2020.3/examining-suspended-program.html#variables)

Loading policies define the way these variables are loaded during the debugging process.
By default, variables are loaded asynchronously. However, in some cases, you don't need to wait for some big data collections, then you can choose the "On Demand" option.

-A.R. PyCharm Web Help